# Azure Logic Apps Issue with Identity

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

We are using logic apps to automatically create Azure Devops work items. But I frequently get issues related to identity if that identity does not already have an existing item assigned to them. Currently, I raise an email alert on this error and I can always create an item manually in ADO and retrigger the logic app. Why does this happen? Is there a fallback that I can use?

For eg. If abc@microsoft.com has never been assigned an item in the ADO and I try to create a work item from the logic app using the Azure Devops connector, it sometimes fails giving error `The identity value 'abc@microsoft.com' for field 'Assigned To' is an unknown identity`.

Please note that manual assignment works.

Comment: Thanks @KevinLu-MSFT, I will try and update you on how this goes

Comment: HI @Ashutosh. To follou up. Could you please check if the answer could solve this issue? If you have any update, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Sure @KevinLu-MSFT, will update you as soon as I try this

Answer (score 0):

> The identity value 'abc@microsoft.com' for field 'Assigned To' is an unknown identity.

It seems that the account identity couldn't be recognized. Based on my test, I could reproduce this issue.

To solve this issue, you could try to set the `assign to` field as `username<useraccount>` format in `Logic app design`. For example: test

[image]

In this case, even if the user is not assigned a work item, the account address can still be identified.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work. I am still getting the same error. It's because the user is not added to the ADO, is there a programmatic way I can do that?